# How to create a csv file that labels unstructured dataset according to filenames

Tags: python, csv, dataset, label

I have an unstructured dataset that consists of audio files. How do I iterate through all files in a given directory (including all files in my subfolders) and label them according to their filenames then store this information in a CSV file?

I am expecting the CSV file to look something like this [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2EQn.png):

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify: ***"label them according to their filenames"***? Do you need the label to be the first and last characters of the filename?

Comment: no the label doesn't have to look like this. The purpose is i want to get the filename and create a label the way i want (for all my files)  and then save this information in a csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The purpose is i want to get
>   the filename and create a label the way i want (for all my files) and
>   then save this information in a csv file

You can use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/glob.html), and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for this task, i.e.:

```
from os import path
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

f_filter = ["mp3", "ogg"] # a list containing the desired file extensions to be matched
m = [] # final match list

for f_path in glob('D:/museu_do_fado/mp3/**', recursive=True): # loop directory recursively
    f_name = path.basename(f_path) # get the filename
    f_ext = f_name.split(".")[-1].lower() # get the file extension and lower it for comparison.

    if f_ext in f_filter: # filter files by f_filter 

        label = "Your choice"
        #label = f_name[0] + f_ext[-1] # as per your example, first char of file_name and last of file_ext
        m.append([f_path, f_name, f_ext, label]) # append to match list
        #print(f_path, f_name, f_name, label)

df = pd.DataFrame(m, columns=['f_path', 'f_name', 'f_ext', 'label']) # create a dataframe from match list
df.to_csv("my_library.csv", index=False) # create csv from df
```

---

Sample `csv`:

```
f_path,f_name,f_ext,label
D:\museu_do_fado\mp3\MDF0001_39.mp3,MDF0001_39.mp3,mp3,Your choice
D:\museu_do_fado\mp3\MDF0001_40.mp3,MDF0001_40.mp3,mp3,Your choice
...
```

---

Notes:

1. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) allows [several export formats](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html), including [to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), [to_pickle()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and `to_csv()` used in the example above, it's a great library to create several types of [data analysis/visualization](https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-with-python-intro-to-data-visualization-and-matplotlib-5f799b7c6d82) of your library. I'd definitively advise you to learn pandas if you can.
2. This answer should give you a starting point, make sure you [read the docs](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python/) if something is off, GL.

Comment: You're welcome @sarah. If my answer helped you, please accept it as the correct answer.